# English translation of dialogues in The Godfather

Tags: the-godfather, translation

Can someone give the English translation of the Italian dialogues between Michael Corleone and Sollozzo?

Comment: http://www.jgeoff.com/godfather/gf1/transcript/gf1transcript.html

Answer (score 15):

Here is the best I could find :

> SOLLOZZO: “I’m sorry…”
>
> MICHAEL: “Leave it alone.” ( or ) “Forget about it.”
>
> SOLLOZZO: “What happened to your father was business. I have much respect for your father. But your father, his thinking is old-fashioned. You must understand why I had to do that.”
>
> MICHAEL: “I understand those things…”
>
> [Waiter brings McCluskey's veal, then exits.]
>
> SOLLOZZO: “Now let’s work through where we go from here.”
>
> MICHAEL: “How do you say… ?” [Then Michael returns to speaking English.]
>
> [After Michael returns from the bathroom]
>
> SOLLOZZO: “Everything all right? I respect myself, understand, and cannot allow another man to hold me back. What happened was unavoidable. I had the unspoken support of the other Family dons. If your father were in better health, without his eldest son running things, no disrespect intended, we wouldn’t have this nonsense. We will stop fighting until your father is well and can resume bargaining. No vengeance will be taken. We will have peace, but your Family should interfere no longer.”

Taken from http://mccluskeysurname.com/mccluskey-family-history/the-godfather-louis-restaurant-scene

Comment: I think the last paragraph is incredibly significant. I have often wondered what Sollozzo's thinking was in trying to kill Vito since during the meeting, Don Corleone says he will not interfere but merely will not lend support. Does this dialog indicate that in fact Vito did somehow try to stop Sollozzo and if so, how?

Answer (score 6):

I've found on Youtube the above piece of dialogue

[The Godfather - Sollozzo and Michael](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSQqv2UuvC0)

and, since I'm italian, I've tried to understand if something is missing or can be edited in Travis's transcription. Most of it is understandable to me but unfortunately, since the actors are speaking (or better say are trying to speak) in sicilian (an italian dialect not easy to understand) I'm not sure about a couple of bits. I've tried to google for the script, but the italian dialogues are not written in the documents I've found. Plus, in the video above I couldn't find a trace of what is written in the last Sollozzo dialogue posted by Travis. Maybe it depends on the fact that that part of dialogue was taken from an extended version?

Anyway, here is my edited version of the dialogue (not much different from the one posted by Travis, just slightly more accurate):

SOLLOZZO: “I’m sorry…”

MICHAEL: “Leave it alone.” ( or ) “Forget about it.”

SOLLOZZO: “What happened to your father was business. I have much respect for your father. But your father, his thinking is old-fashioned and he doesn't want to understand tha I am a man of honor (in sicilian dialect a mafioso is also called a "uomo d'onore")”

MICHAEL: “You don't need to tell me these things. I understand them”

[Waiter brings McCluskey's veal, then exits.]

SOLLOZZO: “You must know that I've helped Tattaglia's family. I think that we can find an agreement. I want peace. Let's cut all this bullshit.”

MICHAEL: "I want to... how do you say...?” [Then Michael returns to speaking English.]

[After Michael returns from the bathroom]

SOLLOZZO: “Do you feel better? Micheluzzo you do understand. You're italian just like your father. Your father is sick. When he feels better let's try to set up a meeting (? - it's very hard to understand this, Sollozzo is chewing words here) and settle everything." (the sound of the whistle covers most of Sollozzo's final words)

Comment: I speak Spanish and a little Italian, and between the two, I was able to make out most of what Solozzo was saying to Michael. I believe that is because the Sicilian dialect is a closer cousin to Spanish than Italian is. Anyway, from my understanding of what is spoken, Pesetas74 your translation is right on! I'll listen again to the last parts that are hard to understand to see if I can make anything else out of what Solozzo says.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a YouTube video showing a subtitled and translated version of the Sicilian conversation between Michael and Sollozzo in Louis' restaurant.