In the movies, The Godfather I and II, is their spoken Italian authentic?
In the movies, The Godfather I (1972) and The Godfather: Part II (1974), especially in The Godfather, Robert De Niro speaks most of his dialogue in Italian.
Robert De Niro is of Italian descent, but he was born in New York.
As I know nothing about Italian, the language, myself. I am wondering how authentic the Italian he speaks in the The Godfather: Part II is.

Puzo and Coppola were of Italian descent. Hard to believe they would not have the actors speak in real Sicilian. This question (regarding subtitle) would imply that the language is authentic. - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84346/why-were-there-no-english-subtitles-provided-during-the-conversation-between-mic

They speak Sicilian, and it's pretty close. For instance, in the restaurant scene, Sollozzo says to Michael:"tu padre pensa antique" (your father thinks archaic/old fashioned/ancient) and it's the same said by a Sicilian or another Italian IIRC. My knowledge of accents isn't good enough to make the difference with just the tone though

Maybe you should ask on https://italian.stackexchange.com.

Funny anecdote: Coppola (or another Sicilian-American film director?) visited his ancestral village. He understood Sicilian but could not speak it. He had a guide who translated from English to Standard Italian but did not understand Sicilian. The locals understood Standard Italian but did not speak it. So conversations went in one-way cycles, Coppola → guide → locals → Coppola …

It's been asked on Italian.SE, and according to a comment by @avpaderno:

"They are speaking Sicilian. 'Padri' is used where in Italian would be 'padre' and I hear an 'eo' instead of 'io'. I am not Sicilian; I could understand the meaning of what said (except some phrases), but that is not "proper" Italian."

That's about all that could be collected as of today, 2 weeks after the question was asked...
